# Error in debug mode

Tags: c#, visual-studio, global-asax

When I run my code in debug mode, I get an exception (System.Web.HttpException: 'Request is not available in this context'), but when I run in release mode (Ctrl-F5), the exception doesn't even show up. The exception appears at the `Server.Transfer` line.

How can I prevent this from happening when I run in debug mode?

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Gets the last error, emails it
        var exc = Server.GetLastError();
        Server.ClearError();

        if (exc == null)
        {
            exc = new ApplicationException("*** Application Exception - Unknown/null exception ***");
        }

        if (exc is HttpException)
        {
            var errorCode = ((HttpException)exc).GetHttpCode();
            Response.Redirect("~/ErrorPage.aspx?e=" + errorCode.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            exc.Publish();

            Server.Transfer("~/ErrorPage.aspx?e=unknown");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server.Transfer can only happen for single HttpContext. Each virtual directory or app has its own HttpContext object and they know not that they co-exists!

You can find a more complete explanation here [Error Message When You Use Server.Transfer or Server.Execute in ASP.NET Page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/320439/prb-error-executing-child-request-error-message-when-you-use-server-tr)

The solution is to change the method for another like **Response.Redirect("~\somepath.aspx");** or  **HttpContext.Current.RewritePath("somepath.aspx");**

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue may be that IIS runs in single-threaded mode when debugging. The `Server.Transfer` queues a message behind the current request which calls it but the current request cannot complete because the `Server.Transfer` cannot complete because the thread is blocked.

Try removing all breakpoints from your initial request and adding one in `ErrorPage.aspx`.

Alternatively, try a `Response.Redirect` instead of `Server.Transfer`. Because `Response.Redirect` will return to the client it completes the current request. I realise this may not be the functionality you require but it will help in debugging, then you can return to `Server.Transfer` for live running.